# Split between 2 characters and making variables of it

Tags: python, list, split

```
listx = ['a', '100', '1-1-2020 12:15:15', 'a->:40, b->:110, c->:30']
```

I want to make variables of 40, 110 and 30 so I can compare them and check for example if ... > ... then....

How to do that? So I actually need to split between `:` and `,`

Comment: I dont undersand your way.... why are you using MAX its taking just the 110?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp there is still la chance to read it... lol

Comment: To prevent further confusion, could you add the expected result to your question?

Comment: @ScootCork check the answer below thats it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listx = ['a', '100', '1-1-2020 12:15:15', 'a->:40, b->:110, c->:30']
numbers = []

for x in listx[3].split(", "):
    numbers.append(int(x[4:]))
num1 = numbers[0]
num2 = numbers[1]
num3 = numbers[2]
print(num1, num2, num3)
```

Comment: I see you are using [4:]. That means the code is quiet fragile, because what do you do when the string becomes sometimes like `a->avg:40` or `avg-->:110`

Comment: You could play the character set what you use.